# Setting QTextDocument painter's rectangle (where to paint)

Tags: html, qt, qtextdocument

I am painting on a window simple html using QTextDocument::drawContents(painter)

I want to do the drawing inside some margins in the window but I don't see a direct way to specify the target rectangle of the painting (in the painter/window).

I guess a few ways to do it:

- Using the QTextDocuments::setMargin (although this does not allow different values for left/top.
- Placing the html into an styled `<div>`
- Applying a translation transform to the painter.

But all this seems a bit too much for what I want to do and I guess if I a missing something straight (as you do with QPainter::drawText where you tell the target rectangle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `textWidth` property to the width of the area where the text is supposed to fit. The clipping rectangle you pass to `drawContents` will cut the text off vertically if there's too much of it to fit; you can't do much about that of course.

So, this would be the missing function you're after:

```
void drawContents(QPainter * p, QTextDocument & doc, const QRectF & rect) {
  p->save();
  p->translate(rect.topLeft());
  doc.setTextWidth(rect.width());
  doc.drawContents(p, rect);
  p->restore();
}
```

Yes, you do need to jump through a few hoops, that's why it needs to be factored out. It's perhaps lamentable that a similar overload of `drawContents` doesn't exist.